# Group question - how to change one element of it?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have sad with group. For example:

```
<xs:group name="custGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="customer" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="orderdetails" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="price" type="xs:float" min="3.2"/>
    <xs:element name="shipto" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="order" type="ordertype"/>

<xs:complexType name="ordertype">
   <xs:group ref="custGroup"/>
   <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now let's say that in one of the places that uses this group ( like order type) I would like to change pace min number for 3.2 to 4.2. How do I do it?

Comment: See following webpage : http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter18.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overriding minOccurs from a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645430/overriding-minoccurs-from-a-group)